# How to check variable arguments data type?

Tags: c, printf

I have a program where am defining a new print function to print some data in required format.
Below is my code;

```
void my_print(int log, int flags,....)
{ 
    format = "| %s | %d | %s | %s";
    printf("%d  %s  ", time,  log);
    vprintf(format, args);
}
```

Before printing my arguments in required format, I want to check whether arguments are in integer format or string format? So how to check data type of the arguments received by `my_print()` ?

Comment: You absolutely can't do that, but then you don't need variable arguments in the first place. Your format string is fixed. The arguments must be string, int, string, string, in that order. So you might as well declare your function that way, instead of relying on `...`.

Comment: `printf("%d  %s  ", time,  log);` has undefined behavior: `log` is an `int`, not a C string pointer.

Comment: @n-pronouns-m, no my format is not fixed. Similar to above defined format i have another 5 formats inside my_print(). Sometimes i send 5 arguments and sometime 7. Also these arguments are of type both integer and string. Hence using va_arg(arg, type) also i cant access since type of argument differs every time

Comment: You still cannot do that. Why do you think `printf` itself doesn't check the arguments? Because it cannot. If you have 5 different formats you probably want to define 5 functions, one for each format, with fixed argument lists.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm., Can i check total number of arguments passed to my function ? Like is it 5 arguments or 6 arguments? is there any C language function available ?

Comment: No, you can't. Why do you think `printf` doesn't do it?